# JavaFX 2D Combobox

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a ComboBox which will show other items when I have the mouse over a current item. Also you cannot select an item which has childs inside.

Like this:

[image: Example]

Currently I have a ComboBox with items of a String array, but I can't understand how to put the child nodes.

Comment: That looks more like a menu than a combo box: are you really using this for *selection of items*, or is some action supposed to be performed when the user clicks on an item? If the latter, just use a `MenuButton` and put `Menu`s in for the sub-menu. The former would be a pretty strange UI, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into what you said. I am using this to do specific action when I click a button, from the selected item in the combobox and also for when a user clicks on a item, it updates a label i have in the gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a `MenuButton` would be a better option than a `ComboBox`. You can do something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Select Item");
        Label label = new Label("Selected Item: ");

        Menu subMenu = new Menu("Item 1");
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) {
            subMenu.getItems().add(createItem("Child item "+i, label));
        }
        menuButton.getItems().add(subMenu);

        for (int i = 2 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            menuButton.getItems().add(createItem("Item "+i, label));
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(label);
        root.setTop(menuButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private MenuItem createItem(String text, Label label) {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(text);
        item.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Selected Item: "+text));
        return item ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```